# Как с помощью JS округлить значение в html-таблице?

Tags: javascript, html

Я в фронтенде совсем новичок, поэтому возможно вопросы совсем элементарные, но без помощи пока не могу обойтись.

У меня есть таблица, в нее я с помощью thymeleaf кладу значения из java-коллекции.
Теперь мне это значение из таблицы нужно округлить до заданного знакак и вернуть обратно в таблицу. Затык именно в том, как это значение с помощью скриптов вытащить, обработать и вернуть, с самой функцией округления вроде все понятно, но вот где этот скрипт прописать и как к нему обратиться, вообще не понимаю.

То есть скрипт примерно такой

```html
<!--кусок таблицы-->
<tr>
  <td>Текст</td>
  <td id="numberOfObs" th:text="${forecastResult.getModelSpecifications().get('numberOfObs')}"><td>
</tr>    

<!--сам скрипт для округления. Скорее всего неправильно, так это для меня абсолютно дикий лес-->
<script>
  var x = document.getElementById("numberOfObs");
  x = Math.floor(x*100)/100
  alert(x);
</script>
```

Вот и как теперь наложить этот скрипт на значение в ячейке 'td'? Как их связать между собой? То есть как это все выглядит в html, если не выносить отдельно скрипты в другой js-файл.

Просто есть скрипты, которые по клику выполняются и прочее, это даже понятнее, так как нужно какое-то действие выполнить. А тут надо чтобы он автоматически сам брал это значение, округлял и вставлял назад в ячейку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!--кусок таблицы-->
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Текст</td>
  <td id="numberOfObs"  th:text="${forecastResult.getModelSpecifications().get('numberOfObs')}"> 
      4.20228
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
<!--сам скрипт для округления.-->
<script>
  var x = document.getElementById("numberOfObs").innerText; // Вынимаем
  x = parseFloat(x); // Тут можно получить NaN если в ячейке не число!
  x = x.toFixed(2);  // Округляем
  document.getElementById("numberOfObs").innerHTML = x; // Вставляем
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Теперь хоть понятно что  и как связано